# Persona 5 - Does the Hawaii date lock in a romance target?

Tags: persona-5

In early August, you go to Hawaii, and as part of that you get the option to go on a date with one of a selection of the Social Link pool: Ann, Makoto, Kawakami or Hifumi - or not choosing any (or not having any available to you) and hanging with Ryuji, Mishima and Yuusuke.

Knowing that romance is an option in the game I'd like to know if selecting one of the girls causes any issues with the romance system, like locking that one in prematurely?

Or does this just play the role of a huge social link boost for a selection of girls to aid with later romancing? As I know hanging with the guys raises none of their social links.

Example: If I chose to go to the beach with Hifumi, will there be any issues if I choose to enter a relationship with any of the other romanceable targets later on? As I know there is a jealousy scene after valentines day if you screw something up with that.

Comment: would love to know what warrented the downvote, as i don't like doing things that would deserve them and try to write well phrased questions

Comment: Ah tons of typos. fair enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the date doesn't lock wich girl you romance. The lock only comes when you reach a certain confidant level, and the game will warn you of the choice

Comment: I found out about that later. For reference, it's Confidant Level 9 in all cases. You get the level update and bonus, then the question is asked as part of the same event.